# Capturing string literals with escaped quotes in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, lexer

I am a bit perplexed about how to capture a quoted string in ANTLR4.

Currently, this lexer rule is not tokenizing the way I expect.

The sample string is `"=\""`. I've tried lots of different ways to capture this, but I am at a loss about what I am doing incorrectly. I'd really appreciate some insights on best practices for this. Thank you so much!

```
ESCAPED_QUOTE : '\"';
QUOTED_STRING :   '"' ( ESCAPED_QUOTE | ~('\n'|'\r') )*? '"';
```

Comment: I came up with this method. It seems to work, but I'm wondering if this is the best way to go about it. Thank you!  ESCAPED_QUOTE : '\"';
QUOTE         : '"';
QUOTED_STRING : QUOTE ( ESCAPED_QUOTE | ~('\n'| '\r' | '\"') )* QUOTE;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two problems with the above rules.

1. You didn't actually escape your quote like you thought. You meant to use `'\\"'`.
2. Your `ESCAPED_QUOTE` rule doesn't form a token all by itself, so it should be a `fragment` rule.

The result of these two changes would be the following:

```
fragment ESCAPED_QUOTE : '\\"';
QUOTED_STRING :   '"' ( ESCAPED_QUOTE | ~('\n'|'\r') )*? '"';
```

Comment: I copied the rule to my grammar and tested. It gives me an error when there are special characters such as ':', '!', ''', etc. That ~('\n'|'\r') regex is supposed to accept anything other than a newline character?